# Custom Dialog while using Google Smartlock on Android

Tags: android, google-smartlockpasswords

How do I customize the android dialog that asks user to select from multiple credentials while using Google Smartlock on Android?

I would like to show the user a custom dialog and not the default dialog

Comment: What are you trying to customize?

Comment: The layout of the dialog, trying to customize it as per my need (my design). Also trying to change the color when a credential is highlighted.

Comment: It's not possible to customize the layout of the dialog, it's a system dialog that's consistent across apps.

Comment: @Steven I am facing some issue in password sync. can you please have a look?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63830860/app-and-website-saved-password-is-not-sync

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to customize the layout of the dialog, it's a system dialog that's consistent across apps.

Comment: thank you for the response, does this also mean that we cannot customize/control what is being fetched by credential api? I get profile images for one saved credentials (gmail) but not for others (gmails). -- Please let me know if this is too broad for this question, I will create another question in that case.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't control that either. Happy to write up answer on a separate question.

Comment: thanks again, here is the updated question, your comments there will definitely help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57585363/smartlock-doesnt-show-user-profile-photo