# SmartLock doesn't show user profile photo

Tags: android, google-smartlockpasswords

I am not able to retrieve the profile image associated with gmail account that is saved to smart lock.

I am trying to integrate smart lock into my android application. I have multiple credentials (Gmail and password) saved to smart lock and these are returned when I make the `CredentialsClient.request()` call. Since there are multiple credentials, a system dialog is shown asking the user to choose the preferred credential. I have noticed that the retrieved credentials don't show the profile picture in the dialog (instead an image of envelop is shown) even though the gmail account has a profile image.

```
CredentialRequest request = new CredentialRequest.Builder()
               .setPasswordLoginSupported(true)
               .build();
```

I use this request object with my `CredentialsClient`.

I would like to show the dialog with the profile picture of the Gmail account.